# DELL PROLIANT SERVER -INSTALLING WITHOUT CD DRIVE

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have a dell proliant server 2500 which has NO CD or DVD drives and no connectors on the motherboard. I want to install operating system and when i check BIOS, boot options, there is only Hard disk and PXE Boot. I need help

FRancis

Comment: There is harddisk **and PXE boot**. So why not use PXE boot ?

Comment: HP Proliant or Dell PowerEdge?

Comment: @fukawi2 there's no 2500 model HP Proliant. They're typically named something like a "DL380 G7." The 2500 model number indicates that it's a Dell.

Comment: @MDMarra I was just highlighting that "Dell Proliant" doesn't exist....

Comment: Maybe he *does* have a Dell Proliant, and is having trouble finding the proper firmware to support boot from USB.

Answer (score 13):

YOU CAN EITHER SET UP PXE OR GET AN INTERNAL DVD/CD DRIVE. THAT SERVER IS TOO OLD TO SUPPORT BOOT FROM USB, SO AN EXTERNAL DEVICE WILL NOT WORK.

ALSO, YOU DO NOT HAVE A DELL PROLIANT, HP MAKES THE PROLIANT LINE. YOU HAVE A DELL POWEREDGE.

Comment: DIDN'T REALISE IT WAS TOO OLD TO SUPPORT BOOTING FROM USB DEVICES!

Comment: YA, I HAD ISSUES USB BOOTING 2650S BEFORE, SO I CANT IMAGINE THAT A 2500 WILL WORK.

Comment: THIS IS THE ONLY TIME I WOULD UPVOTE AN ANSWER IN ALL CAPS.